# How to transfer data from a callback to another view in Django?

Tags: django, callback

I have a function that makes a request to Erlang. Next, the Erlang sends a response to the url callback. I need this data in the original function to verify the success of the operation. Accordingly, the original function must wait until an answer arrives. `mfs_create_and_activate` starts request to Erlang. There are several more functions, adding them I do not see the point. As a result, there comes json, in which a detailed answer, I only need HTTP code from there. How do I transmit this data?

**Original function:**

```
def pay(request):
    try:
        body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        if not body:
            raise ValidationError('empty query')
        body = json.loads(body)
        for field_name in ['phone', 'amount', 'merchant_name', 'payment_type', 'prefix', 'number']:
            check_field(body, field_name)
    except ValidationError as error:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': error.message
            },
        })
    except JSONDecodeError:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': 'not Json or incorrect Json'
            },
        })
    active_subs = MfsSubscription.objects.filter(
        phone=body.get('phone'),
        is_subscribe=True,
    )
    if not active_subs.exists():
        response = mfs_create_and_activate(body.get('phone'))
        logger.info('activate code = {}'.format(response['code']))
        if response is None:
            return JsonResponse({
                'status': 'failed',
                'errors': {
                    'code': 500,
                    'message': 'Connection timeout',
                },
            })
        else:
            if response['code'] == 201 or response['code'] == 200:
                'check data from callback function and next actions'
```

**Callback function:**

```
    @csrf_exempt
def callbackpay(request):
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))#here is the answer from Erlang
        logger.info('Callback with post data: {}'.format(data))
        phone = data['details']['payment_source']['details']['msisdn']
        handler = callback_factory(data['action'])
        response = JsonResponse({}, status=500)
        if handler:
            response = handler(phone, data)
        return JsonResponse({}, status=response.status_code)
    except (
            KeyError, Service.DoesNotExist, Service.MultipleObjectsReturned,
            MfsSubscription.DoesNotExist,
            MfsSubscription.MultipleObjectsReturned
    ) as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return JsonResponse({}, status=500)
```

Comment: are you forced to wait for the callback in the first view?

Comment: Yes, the further scenario will depend on the result.

Comment: Which function is the one that makes a request to Erlang? Which is "the original function"? Your description is a bit confusing when trying to understand the code you included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if is something I don't like, a possible solution (if you can't change the API) is

in the `pay` view:

- send the request to Erlang
- save a record in the DB for the sent request
- poll (loop with a sleep) until the DB says the `callbackpay` has been called

for instance in `callbackpay` you can store something in the DB to notify the results are available.

If you are using an in-memory solution (Redis, memcached, ....) you can store these temporary data in memory instead of writing in a DB record